# Implement Server Send Events with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server-sent-events

I'm trying to implement server send events in Rails 4 running on passenger.  The aim is send the client updates when a active record changes.

There is a pretty neat example in php over here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31255914

But I was wondering how this is achieved in rails.  Is there any specific configuration required for rails to manage the connections ?

Comment: https://github.com/rails/actioncable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live.html

Just include the Action Controller live, and write a simple action:

```
class MyController < ActionController::Base
  include ActionController::Live

  def stream
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
    100.times {
      response.stream.write "hello world\n"
      sleep 1
    }
  ensure
    response.stream.close
  end
end
```