Why aren't SSE messages automatically rendering in my app's live feed?
I'm building a CRM application that uses Server-Sent Events to receive real-time updates for new messages (pretty simplistic chat UI). While the messages update when I click on a user in the conversation list, the frontend doesn't automatically update when new data comes in through the webhook. Here's the relevant code:
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { getToken } from './auth';

class SSEManager {
  constructor() {
    this.eventSource = null;
    this.listeners = {};
  }

  connect() {
    if (!this.eventSource) {
      this.eventSource = new EventSource('/api/sms/sse');
      this.eventSource.onmessage = this.handleMessage.bind(this);
      this.eventSource.onerror = this.handleError.bind(this);
    }
  }

  handleMessage(event) {
    try {
      const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
      if (this.listeners[data.type]) {
        this.listeners[data.type].forEach(callback => callback(data));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error processing SSE message:', error);
    }
  }


const sseManager = new SSEManager();

export const useSSE = (eventType, callback) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    sseManager.connect();
    sseManager.addEventListener(eventType, callback);

    return () => {
      sseManager.removeEventListener(eventType, callback);
      if (Object.keys(sseManager.listeners).length === 0) {
        sseManager.disconnect();
      }
    };
  }, [eventType, callback]);
};

export const fetchContactMessages = async (contactId) => {
  try {
    const token = getToken();
    const response = await fetch(`/api/contacts/${contactId}?includeMessages=true`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch contact and messages');
    }
    return await response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching contact and messages:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};

In my component, I'm using the useSSE hook like this:
useSSE('newMessage', async (data) => {
  if (contact && data.contactId === contact._id) {
    await fetchContactMessagesData();
  }
});

The fetchContactMessagesData function is defined as:
const fetchContactMessagesData = useCallback(async () => {
  if (!contact) return;

  setLoading(true);
  setError('');
  try {
    const data = await fetchContactMessages(contact._id);
    if (data.messages && Array.isArray(data.messages)) {
      setMessages(data.messages);
      messagesCache.current[contact._id] = data.messages;
    } else {
      setMessages([]);
      messagesCache.current[contact._id] = [];
    }
    if (data.firstName !== contact.firstName || data.lastName !== contact.lastName) {
      onUpdateContact({...contact, ...data});
    }
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching contact and messages:', error);
    setError('Failed to fetch messages. Please try again later.');
    toast.error('Failed to fetch messages');
    throw error;
  } finally {
    setLoading(false);
  }
}, [contact, onUpdateContact]);

I am relatively new to web development and this is the first time I am making an app that utilizes SSE. My main 2 questions would be Am I setting up the SSE connection correctly and is there an issue with how I'm handling the new message event in the component? Pretty lost here so any help would be greatly appreciated!
I believe I have already set up the backend properly, I did some logging and it seems like the SSE is properly emitting to the client-side. The SSE connection on the network tab in dev tools says its 200. I am not 100% sure if the data is being sent over to the frontend successfully, the EventStream tab is empty but I have also read that it may be a bug on googles part.

I'd add a console.log(data) in handleMessage(), just after the JSON.parse() call. If you see these that confirms the data is getting that far. Note that if data.type doesn't match an entry in this.listeners the message gets ignored. (I can expand this to a proper answer if that is on the right track.)

@DarrenCook Not sure if you'd know whats going on, but I added more logging, and make the backend send periodic test messages. When I monitor the eventstream on the network dev tools nothing appears, but strangely, as soon as I save any change to my webhook controller file, or sse manager file, the web app recompiles and all of the test messages that were send all the sudden populate within the eventstream (note that this is still for the old sse connection, a new one is also created and that one will not show any events in the eventstream unless I recompile again...)

I'd add that information to the main question as it now sounds like a server-side issue. Try using curl to connect to the backend to simplify troubleshooting (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31255914/841830)

@DarrenCook Just used curl the same way as in the recommended thread. It seems to work just fine, not sure what the problem in the browser is but Im not sure if it is server side since this is working? Here's the curl C:\Users\myuser>curl -N http://localhost:6000/api/sms/sse
data: {"type":"connected","message":"SSE connection established"}
data: {"type":"keepalive","message":"Connection alive"}
data: {"type":"keepalive","message":"Connection alive"}

@DarrenCook Just figured it out! Apparently chrome wasnt happy with me running my backend on port 6000 I switched it to 8080 and everything works fine.
